# How do I set control colors to match Windows Office 2007 color settings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, colors, infragistics, color-scheme

I've been working with some Infragistics components that can have an office 2007 style applied to them, and they use one of the three styles, Blue, Black or Silver, with some customization options, and an AppStylist Feature to make custom Color/Style Libraries.

What I need to do, is match the colors that Windows has set for these styles, dynamically, as the User may change their settings, and there are certain components that need to match these colors, that will not be updated by the Style Libraries because they are not Infragistics components.  (i.e. a Third Party graphing tool plugin background color)

I'm trying to determine where these color values would be stored, and how they could be accessed.

My thoughts so far, would be to Grab the color of the Infragistics controls and convert it to RBG and then use it for the other controls.

Another solution might be to use SystemColors, but I'm not sure if these match the Office 2007 Style.

The most annoying solution, but maybe the best, would be to exclusively use Infragistics components, but in the case of the graphing tool, this wouldn't be 100% possible.

The end goal is to get a nice background color for the Graphs I'm using in my software, and to change the currently Ugly grey Pop-up windows.

Comment: I'm asking this mostly because a number of different google searches produced no satisfactory results.  Perhaps because nobody wishes to change colors in their programs to match office 2007...  or because if they did, they would just make the colors fixed..  so they could just use the dropper from a paint program to get the colors...

Comment: I think the answer should be somewhere around SystemColors. However, this question sounds like too broad for the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm on the wrong Q&A site?  Is the question too broad for StackExchange?

Comment: You picked the right site, i.e. SO. But I fear this question is too broad for any StackExchange website. Here people provide answers, not solutions, most likely because help is free, and nobody is willing to dedicate a lot of time to answer a single question.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I did find part of an answer.  Office2007ColorTable is an table object that contains all of the colors used for infragistics.  It's populated by the specific color scheme used.  I made an excel table documenting all of the colors and started filling it in with every color so I can easily tell what is what.

Comment: If you are actually looking to get the values from a Style Library or a StyleSet, this will be difficult because the StyleLibraryInfo and StyleSetInfo classes are internal.  It may be easier to parse the XML of the .isl file directly if you know what values you are looking to get/use.